# Kubernetes Redis Cluster PubSub Channels not getting synched on replica

Tags: redis, kubernetes, stackexchange.redis

I have set up a Redis cluster on Kubernetes, the cluster state is OK and the replica is connected to the master. Also as per the logs, the full synchronization is also completed. The logs are as follows:-

```
9:M 22 Oct 12:24:18.209 * Slave 192.168.1.41:6379 asks for synchronization
9:M 22 Oct 12:24:18.209 * Partial resynchronization not accepted: Replication ID mismatch (Slave asked for '794b9c74abe40ac90c752f32a102078e063ff636', my replication IDs are '0f499740a46665d12fab921838297273279ad136' and '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000')
9:M 22 Oct 12:24:18.209 * Starting BGSAVE for SYNC with target: disk
9:M 22 Oct 12:24:18.211 * Background saving started by pid 231
231:C 22 Oct 12:24:18.215 * DB saved on disk
231:C 22 Oct 12:24:18.216 * RDB: 4 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
9:M 22 Oct 12:24:18.224 * Background saving terminated with success
9:M 22 Oct 12:24:18.224 * Synchronization with slave 192.168.1.41:6379 succeeded
```

Still, when I check the List of the PubSub Channels on the replica, it does not show the channels and thus it breaks the PubSub flow.

Any help/advise is appreciated.

Comment: Is it a delay or it doesn't show the values at all?

Comment: so... if you `subscribe` on the replica, and `publish` on the master, are you saying that the client doesn't get the broadcast?